# How do I preserve a Vaadin view instance when navigating between views

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I have a view which is quite heavy with data. The data is loaded when the view is initialized. Now, when I navigate away from the view using Router and then return to the view, a new view instance is created triggering refetching of all the data. I would like to preserve the original view instance even when returning to the view - how can this be achieved?

Edit:
To add details, this is a Spring Boot application and unlike to my expectation, annotating a view as @UIScope didn't keep the instance, but a new instance was created every time when navigating to the view.

Comment: What is heavy? Loading the data from db to the middleware, or sending it from the middleware to the frontend?
If the first, add some caching of the data in the middleware

Comment: In this case, it's loading the data from an external API. Caching the data in the middleware is a viable option, but a total overkill for this very simple application. Another use case is simply having a large form lose all its user-entered data when navigating back and forth (e.g. to check a detail from another view). There are countless use cases where you want to preserve the state of the view between navigations.

Comment: A theoretical way would be abusing a RouterLayout.  Create an intermediate layout with all the heavy content in it.  Then use the layout in the now basically empty view. If you are using Spring you could make the heavy content a component with `@UIScope`. But be aware, that UI is bascially the highest you can get (you can not share components between UIs).  So basically the heavy content will still be created once per User/Browser/... So maybe adding a caching layer for all users would still be the best solution.  If only to defend against problems with the remote API.

Answer (score 4):

Answering my own question, in case someone else runs into the same situation.

I had a Spring Boot application, so the first step was to define the scope for the views so that they wouldn't be recreated, a suitable scope is UIScope. However, that is not enough, even though injecting of beans work out-of-the-box, the views don't seem to be managed beans by default, so adding @Component annotation to the view makes them managed and thus, the @UIScope scoping also starts working.

```
@UIScope
@PreserveOnRefresh
@PageTitle("example")
@Route(value = "example", layout = MainLayout.class)
@Component
public class ExampleView extends VerticalLayout {
```

Comment: FYI, @PreserveOnRefresh will NOT preserve the UI and therefore also not any objects in the UI scope. So this will work as you expect while navigating in the application. But when refreshing, everything in the UI scope that is not part of the current view will be disposed.